# How to send data to two tables with same user ID as primary key?

Tags: php, html, mysql, sql

I am totally new to PHP and I'm trying to create a registration page. To register, a user has to create a username, password, email, which are put into a table called `users`.

They also enter address details which is put into a table called `customer_info`.

In both tables I have created an auto increment, primary key called 'user_id'.

When the form is completed it fills out and enters the data, but the data is not banded and so there are two user_id, one in `users` and one in `customer_info`.

First I create values (from the post) that have been entered and assign them to variables. Then I put the variables into my table using the following query:

```
$result = mysql_query(
    "INSERT INTO `users`(username, password, email) VALUES ('$value1', '$value2','$value3')"
);
```

and

```
$result = mysql_query(
    "INSERT INTO `customer_info`(firstname, lastname, b_add_num, b_add_road, b_add_town, b_add_pc, p_add_num, p_add_road, p_add_town, p_add_pc) VALUES ('$value4','$value5','$value6','$value7','$value8','$value9','$value10','$value11','$value12','$value13')"
);
```

How would I set it so that it creates only one user id for both tables (making a connection between the sets of data)?

Is there something missing in my query, that should connect the tables?

Comment: And i guess auto-generated user_id are different in table users and in table customer_info ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Before anything**, you should not use mysql_* extension anymore. Go towards [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) or [mysqli](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php)

---

Your technique generates two different unique ids. The point is to have only *one*, so that it can be unique, and link information on that unique id.

The users table is the one with that unique id, `user_id`, which is your auto_increment column. The customer_info table can also have a `info_id` unique column, but must contain a `user_id` column, which will contain the user's `user_id`, linking the rows together.

It would also be a great moment to add a [foreign key](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3722306/576767) to your tables so that integrity of the data won't be compromised.

so after this query:

```
$result = mysql_query(
    "INSERT INTO `users`(username, password, email) VALUES ('$value1', '$value2','$value3')"
);
```

get the insert id:

```
$id = mysql_insert_id();
```

then run your other query with it:

```
$result = mysql_query(
    "INSERT INTO `customer_info`(user_id,firstname, lastname, b_add_num, b_add_road, b_add_town, b_add_pc, p_add_num, p_add_road, p_add_town, p_add_pc) VALUES ('$id','$value4','$value5','$value6','$value7','$value8','$value9','$value10','$value11','$value12','$value13')"
);
```

Comment: Thanks man !!!! the answer below is right but tbh I have been in front of a screen for so long my mind is turning to mush, just needed the active example from Fractal! :)

Answer (score 3):

I would configure `USER_ID` as an AUTO_INCREMENT column only in `Users` table, insert the data into `Users` table first, then get the ID of the user inserted, using the `mysql_insert_id ($connection_id);` and use that while inserting data into `Customer_Info` table. This way, you can leverage the ID generation (sequence) feature of MySQL as well.

Comment: `mysql_insert_id` should be called after an insert into a table that has `AUTO_INCREMENT` column. The parameter is the connection id that is used to insert the record, so that `mysql_insert_id` can fetch the value of the AUTO_INCREMENT column for the latest record inserted.

Comment: I tried this: 

` mysql_insert_id ($connection_id);
 
 $result = mysql_query("INSERT INTO `customer_info`(user_id, firstname, lastname, b_add_num, b_add_road, b_add_town, b_add_pc, p_add_num, p_add_road, p_add_town, p_add_pc) VALUES ('$connection_id',` but is coming up with undefined variable. 

Please correct me if i am wrong but my understanding is that `$connection_id` is the `user_id` that has just been created because of the auto increment, so are we trying to put that info into the `user_id` of the other table?

Comment: $connection_id is the ID of the connection object to the database. It is not the user_id. How does your mysql_query know which database to run the query on? It should take some connection parameter right? that same connection parameter should be passed to `mysql_insert_id` function as well.

Comment: I'm sorry, i'm not following, maybe im being half sighted but could you give me an example of the `mysql_insert_id ($connection_id);` in use with my code?