# PHP/SQL/PDO registration with multiple tables (users, details)

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I would like to know some ways how to create a registration system with separated tables users and profiles.

```
+----------------+
| Tables_in_mydb |
+----------------+
| profiles       |
| users          |
+----------------+
```

Users:

```
+----------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field    | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+----------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| User_ID  | int(11)      | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| Username | varchar(45)  | YES  | UNI | NULL    |                |
| EMail    | varchar(45)  | YES  | UNI | NULL    |                |
| Password | varchar(150) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| Reg_Date | datetime     | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
+----------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

Profiles:

```
+------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field      | Type        | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Profile_ID | int(11)     | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| fname      | varchar(45) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| lname      | varchar(45) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| User_ID    | int(11)     | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
+------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

Registration is working, it uses users table.
But I want something like when I click on user name I will see his detailed profile page and I'm not sure how to do it.
What methods? When user registers should be created empty profiles table connected to users? Or create profiles table only when he fills rows?
And how to do that?
Later I would like to add news table. User can write news, post it and there will be author and linked to his profile.

I don't know how to do that in php neither can find any information on google.

Answer (score 1):

If you're going to invest some time learning how to do user registration, login authentication and adding additional pages for authenticated users with PHP/SQL/PDO you might as well look at a complete set of code and branch out additional features by looking at a complete set of code.

Here is a good example,

```
 https://github.com/daveismyname/loginregister
```

1. using this set of code will teach you to do it in object oriented php and you'll be exposed to using mysql PDO sql statements. This is time consuming and it's not as much as using a framework. This option is recommended. This is how it should be setup for starters.
2. If you're looking something more robust and want to suggest you use a framework like CodeIgniter. http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/#tutorial
   this methodology will require you to understand MVC Model View Controller in order to build out features. This is very time consuming and much rewarding when it's done.
3. If you're looking for a CMS, I'd use Wordress https://wordpress.org/download/. You can add features by adding plugins such as login, register and by customizing functionality in the back office. This is a faster approach and less time consuming.

Comment: Thank you for pointing me, but I've already have a registration page. I meant how to connect those two tables. But I have found something using mysql_insert_id(); http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20384834/how-to-send-data-to-two-tables-with-same-user-id-as-primary-key

Comment: You're welcome. I used to use older mysql functions in some of my old scripts. I saw ton of posts on here people suggesting to use mysql pdo functions to avoid sql injection.

Answer (score 0):

You can include the two input fields for `First_Name` & `Last_Name` along with other information in your sign up/Registration page. Something like [this](http://codepen.io/ehermanson/pen/KwKWEv)

Or

You just let them register without it and later ask them to complete their profile.