# Add database "sub-table" per element

Tags: php, mysql

I'm not sure if a "sub-table" is the proper term for it, so let me explain a bit better.

I'm setting up a website which contains multiple items, now I've created 2 separate tables in my MySQL database: `general` and `platforms`.

My goal now is to split the data of each item into these 2 tables, which works fine so far, but my problem now is the following:

The `platforms` table has the following structure:

```
ID
Name
URL
```

I want to keep track of each item by their `ID`, so the `ID` for `item #1` should be equal in all tables.

Now, if I have say 3 different platforms for `item #1`, I'll add every element in the `platforms` table, but their `ID`'s don't match.

And if I have multiple items, each with multiple platforms it will start to look really messy.

Is it possible to have a table that looks like this?

```
ID
    Name
    URL
```

[image: How it currently is]
[image: How I want it]

Hopefully the images clarify it more, basically; I want to have a table that groups together multiple elements.

Is this possible or would I have to do it by assigning a secondary non auto-incrementing ID to each item and manually group the platforms together in PHP?

Comment: Googled on `foreign keys?`  Thought you were asking about an xref style join table... Think though you just need to read up some on FKs.  See; http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1730837/can-someone-explain-mysql-foreign-keys and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/83147/whats-wrong-with-foreign-keys

Comment: @ficuscr It looks like FKs could work, I'm reading http://www.sitepoint.com/mysql-foreign-keys-quicker-database-development/ right now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you have a one-to-many relationship. Generically, that means

a row in `general` can be related to zero, one or more rows in `platforms`.

a row in `platforms` is related to exactly one row in `general`.

To implement this design, store the `id` value from the `general` table as a *foreign key* in the `platforms` table.

```
id
general_id    -- foreign key references id in general table
name
url
```

Rows in the two tables are related by virtue of a common value.

```
  id  general_id  name        url
 ---  ----------  ---------  --------------------------
  77           1  Platform1  http://item1.com/platform1
  78           1  Platform2  http://item1.com/platform2
  79           1  Platform3  http://item1.com/platform3
```

---

To have the database *enforce* referential integrity, you would need to use a storage engine that supports that (e.g. InnoDB), and you can declare a constraint

```
ALTER TABLE `platforms` ADD 
 `general_id`  INT NOT NULL COMMENT 'fk ref general.id' AFTER `id`;
```

(The datatype of the `general_id` columns must exactly match the datatype of the `id` column in the `general` table.)

Before you can enforce the constraint, the values in the new `general_id` column will have to match a value in the referenced column.

To define the constraint:

```
ALTER TABLE `platforms`
  ADD CONSTRAINT FK_platforms_general
  FOREIGN KEY (`general_id`) REFERENCES `general`(`id`)
```